# Eigenvalue and eigenspace problem

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $S=\{1,2, \cdots,n\}$ be a non-empty set and $P(S)$ be the power
>   set of $S$. In this set up $P(S)$ is a vector space over the field
>   $\mathbb{F}_2$, and the vector addition is given by symmetric
>   difference of sets, that is for $A_1,A_2 \in P(S)$
>
> $$A_1+A_2=(A_1-A_2) \cup (A_2-A_1)$$
>
> Now fixed an element $B \in P(S)$ and define a liner transformation
>   $f:P(S) \to P(S)$ given by
>
> $$f(A)=A\cap B$$
>
> Questions:
>
> 1) Find the eigenvalue and eigenspace of $f$
>
> 2) If $B=\{1,2, \cdots ,m\}$, find the minimal polynomial,
>   characteristic polynomial and the Jordan normal form of $f$.

Facts (previous questions):

a) $\emptyset$ is the zero element of $P(S)$ and the addition inverse of $A$ is itself.

b) $P(S)$ has an basis $\{\{1 \},\{2 \},\cdots,\{ n\} \}$, hence $\dim(P(S))=n$

c) $\ker(f)=P(S-B)$

d) $\text{Im}(f)=P(B)$

If I can write down a matrix for $f$ than I know how to do these 2 questions, however I don't know how to fine such matrix. So, I just try to write down something and see how's it goes.

Let $\lambda$ and $V$ be the eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector of $f$ and $E_{\lambda}$ be the eigenspace of the corresponding $\lambda$, so now we have

$$  f(V)=V \cap B=\lambda V$$

as $0 \cdot V =\emptyset$, $1 \cdot V=V$, so we have that $\lambda V=V$ or $\emptyset$

This gives $\lambda=1$ or $0$

To find $E_1$, I look at $f(V)=V$ and intuition tells me that $E_1=\text{Im}(f)$. Same for $E_0$, when I look at $f(V)=\emptyset$ I feel like it is equal to $\ker(f)$.

For question 2) I remember that minimal polynomial has something to do with eigenvalues, so if $m(X)$ is the minimal polynomial, it should of the form

$$m(X)=X^a (X-1)^b$$

Any help would be thankful.

Comment: What is $\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: @zoli It is $\mathbb{F}_2=GF(2)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

In general, if $\mathbb F$ is a field and $\mathbb V$ is an $n$ dimensional  vector space over that field then $\mathbb V$ can be represented as vectors

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{bmatrix}, \ x_i\in \mathbb F, \ i=1,2,...,n.$$

In our case $\mathbb F_2=\{0,1\}$ with the addition and multiplication tables are:

$$\begin{matrix}
&&\color{red}+&&&&&\color{blue}{\cdot}\\
&0&&1&&&0&&1\\
0&\color{red}0 &&\color{red}1&&&\color{blue}0&&\color{blue}0\\
1&\color{red}1&&\color{red}0&&&\color{blue}0&&\color{blue}1
\end{matrix}  $$

We have to show the isomorphism between the set representation and the vector representation of $P(S)$.

The basis given by the OP. Every set is represented by a vector that contains a $1$ at the element that belongs to the set and a zero at the element that does not belong to the set.

Multiplying by $1$ does not change the vector and multiplying by $0$ chages the vector to the one representing the empty set (full of zeros.)

Vector addition corresponds to the symmetric difference. For example, let $n=3$ and take the two sets and the corresponding two vectors:
$$A=\{1\} \text{ and }, B=\{1,3\}\ ; v_A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right],v_B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right].$$

The addition in the language of sets

$$A+B=A\cap\overline B \cup B\cap \overline A=\{1\}\cap\{2\}\cup\{1,3\}\cup\{2,3\}=\{3\}.$$

The same in vector notation:

$$v_A+v_B=\begin{bmatrix}1+1\\0+0\\0+1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=v_{\{3\}}.$$

The question is, now, the form of the matrix belonging to the set operation $$f_B=A\cap B.$$
If for instance

$$B=\{2,3\}$$
then

$$f_B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$Indeed, for $A=\{1,3\}$; $v_A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\1
\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

$$A\cap B=\{3\}\text{ and } f_Bv_A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}=v_{\{3\}}.$$

The eigenvector of $f_B$ then is $v_B$ with the eigenvalue $1$.

I just hope that the isomorphism shown helps to answer the remaining questions.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot :)